# I am trying to render the pdf in my react app its saying failed to load pdf file

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

my console is saying
GET http://localhost:3000/static/media/sample1.27912b28acd382c64eb8.pdf net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: Share your Code for us to understand better your question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**this problem trigger when your browser have extensions that intercept the connection like IDM,AdBlocker... disable these  extensions and try again its work for me !**